# mybatis xml config file cannot be parsed

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a problem reading the xml config file for MyBatis 3.0.2.

I have to use it in a web service with Axis2 1.5. I have a class whith this code:

```
public static org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory getSqlMapper () {
    org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory sqlMapper;
    try {
        String resource = "MyBatis.xml";
        java.io.Reader reader = org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
        sqlMapper = new org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Si hay un error en este punto, no importa cual sea. Será un error irrecuperable del cual
        // nos interesará solo estar informados.
        // Deberás registrar el error y reenviar la excepción de forma que se te notifique el
        // problema de forma inmediata.
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException ("Error initializing MyAppSqlConfig class. Cause: " + e);
    }
    return sqlMapper;
}
```

Where MyBatis.xml is the config file. When I call to `getSqlMapper`, in the line `sqlMapper = new org...` I get this exception:

> ```
> loader constraint violation: when resolving field "NODE" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, javax/xml/namespace/QName, have different Class objects for that type
> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "NODE" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, javax/xml/namespace/QName, have different Class objects for that type
>  at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:158)
>  at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>  at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
>  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
>  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:167)
>  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:142)
>  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
>  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
>  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
>  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
>  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
>  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:194)
>  at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
>  ... 27 more
> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "NODE" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, javax/xml/namespace/QName, have different Class objects for that type
>  at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.evalNode(XPathParser.java:169)
>  at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.evalNode(XPathParser.java:165)
>  at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parse(XMLConfigBuilder.java:55)
>  at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:29)
>  at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:15)
>  at es.adif.sgmm.sc.srv.servicio.util.MyBatisUtils.getSqlMapper(MyBatisUtils.java:30)
>  at es.adif.sgmm.sc.srv.servicio.impl.RecepDAO.crearNotificacion(RecepDAO.java:30)
>  at es.adif.sgmm.sc.srv.servicio.impl.ReceptorNotificacion.notificarReal(ReceptorNotificacion.java:40)
>  ... 33 more
> ```

I have read a lot on the internet about errors like this but it brings me to no where. It seems to be a problem with the class `javax.xml.namespace.Qname` that should be defined in two different places but I don't know how to fix it.

Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2009/03/javalanglinkageerror-loader-constraint.html) might be of use. The notable part is that the *sequence* of loading classes is a factor as well, not just the *presence* of the same class in two JARs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll try it and I hope that this will resolve the problem.